# How to get item’s custom attribute’s value on customer manage view page?

Tags: magento

I have added an attribute Account number having textbox  in Account information section of customer page in admin.Now i want to show the value of that attribute in customer manage view page. I have already added one column for account number in customer manage view page but whatever the value i am adding, it is not showing on customer manage view page.
If anyone have any idea about this, please help me out.
thanks!

I have added the below code for creating a new column in manage customer page path

```
app/code/core/Mage/AdminHtml/Block/Customers/Grid.php

$this->addColumn('billing_Number', array(
            'header'    => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Account Number'),
            'width'     => '150',
            'index'     => 'billing_Number',
        ));
```

This created a new column of account no but not showing their data under that.i want to know how to fetch data of account no. I think now you have understand

Comment: Please post your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: plz tell me it is very urgent how to show the value in customer view page..........